# Uncaught TypeError: Person is not a constructor

Tags: javascript

```js
var Person = (function () {
    var name = Symbol('name');
    class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this[name] = name
    }
    getname() {
        return this[name];
    }
  }
}());

var person = new Person();
console.log(person.getname())
```

I'm making a small example via a tutorial on Google. This example prevents to access property this.name from outside scope. But I'm getting error

> Uncaught TypeError: Person is not a constructor.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you link us the tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return Person class and use another variable name for storing symbol since it's the same as constructor argument name:

```js
var Person = (function () {
    var nameSymbol = Symbol('name');
    return class Person {
      constructor(name) {
          this[nameSymbol] = name;
      }
      getname() {
          return this[nameSymbol];
      }
  }
}());

var person = new Person('John');
console.log(person.getname())
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function Person (name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.getname=function() {
        return this[name];
    };
}

var person = new Person('name');
console.log(person.getname())
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to enclose class within a function. ES5 needs functions to create a class. The code snippet you have provides makes a mix of ES5 and ES6. Simple use as below:

```
    class Person {
      constructor(name) {
          this.name = name
      }
      getname() {
          //return this.name;
          return this['name'];
      }
  }

  let person = new Person('Alex');
  console.log(person.getname());
```

If you are using [] notation to access object properties then remember that it must be a string i.e.wrapped in quotes